# tcolorbox, not displaying symbols in listings (using minted)

Tags: symbols, tcolorbox, minted, code

I have the following latex code

```
\begin{ipythonnb}
\begin{ipyin}
A = np.array([[3, 2, -1], [2, -2, 4], [-1, 0.5, -1]])
b = np.array([1, -2, 0])
np.linalg.solve(A,b)
\end{ipyin}
\begin{ipyout}
array([ 1., -2., -2.])
\end{ipyout}
\begin{ipyin}
Ai = np.linalg.inv(A)
np.dot(Ai, b)
\end{ipyin}
\begin{ipyout}
array([ 1., -2., -2.])
\end{ipyout}
\begin{ipyin}
Ai
\end{ipyin}
\begin{ipyout}

\end{ipyout}
\begin{ipyout2}
array([[  2.22044605e-16,  -5.00000000e-01,  -2.00000000e+00],
       [  6.66666667e-01,   1.33333333e+00,   4.66666667e+00],
       [  3.33333333e-01,   1.16666667e+00,   3.33333333e+00]])
\end{ipyout2}
\end{ipythonnb}
```

with the following declarations, separately

```
\newlength{\inwd}
\setlength{\inwd}{1.8cm}

\newcounter{ipythcntr}
\setcounter{ipythcntr}{0}

\DeclareTColorBox{ipythonnb}{}{colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,
breakable,
title=\setcounter{ipythcntr}{0}IPython Session,
title after break=IPython Session (cont.), fonttitle=\bfseries}

\DeclareTCBListing{ipyin}{ o }{
    enlarge left by=\inwd,
    width=\linewidth-\inwd,
    boxrule=0.4pt,
    enhanced,
    listing only,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    left=0pt,
    opacityframe=0,
    opacityback=0,
    overlay={
        \node[
            anchor=north east,
            text width=\inwd,
            font=\ttfamily\color{blue!50!black},
            inner ysep=6pt,
            inner xsep=0pt,
            outer sep=0pt
        ]
        at (frame.north west)
        {\IfValueTF{#1}{\setcounter{ipythcntr}{#1}}{\stepcounter{ipythcntr}}In [\theipythcntr]:};
    }
    listing engine=minted,minted language=python,
    minted options={breaklines}
    }

\DeclareTCBListing{ipyout}{ }{
    enlarge left by=\inwd,
    width=\linewidth-\inwd,
    boxrule=0.4pt,
    enhanced,
    listing only,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    left=0pt,
    opacityframe=0,
    opacityback=0,
    overlay={
        \node[
            anchor=north east,
            text width=\inwd,
            font=\ttfamily\color{red!75!black},
            inner ysep=1pt,
            inner xsep=0pt,
            outer sep=0pt
        ]
        at (frame.north west)
        {Out [\theipythcntr]:};
    }
    }

\DeclareTCBListing{ipyout2}{ }{
    boxrule=0.4pt,
    enhanced,
    listing only,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    left=0pt,
    opacityframe=0,
    opacityback=0,
    }
    }
```

It's generating the following output:
[image: Generated Output]

I can't work out whats happing to the minus signs, I have found a few other posts, one affecting listing where another package muddled the symbols, and the other were the minus signs were unicode symbols, I've manually replace all minus signs using the keyboard hence that shouldn't be the problem, and I'm not using the listings package, rather minted, hence the solution isn't useful here.

I've also had other symbols disappear. such as angled and curly brackets.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I've attempted to create a minimal working example however, the error doesn't occur in this example. And I can't find any reason why it would be occurring in my main project but not my example.

Comment: I have now incrementally extended my Minimal working example, until it reproduce the original document, exactly (excluding some comments), with out the error occurring.

Comment: I have now attempted rebuilding my original document yet the error still occurs, Note I'm also getting some other errors from pypigments, which I haven't looked into yet, could these be causing the problem:

Comment: Wouldn't fit:
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...default@bf {\PYGdefault@ff {\PYGZsh 
                                                  {}!/usr/bin/env python}}
l.2 \PYG{c}{\PYGZsh{}!/usr/bin/env python}
                                          
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: I had assumed these were related to the pypigments package, but the example, that was identical didn't produce these errors either.

Comment: Ok I've fixed the problem now, however still don't understand whats happening, I found the files causing the errors, were in _minted_main, (main.tex is project file) there was also a _minted_example folder (example.tex was my minimal example) I deleted both these folders then rebuild main.tex, and it worked with out error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP found its bug making a MWE.